# Rigging a loose character belt that's easy to move around/deform when character is posed/animated

Tags: rigging

I'm probably overthinking this, but...

What would be good way to rig this loose belt so that it's relatively easy to move around when the character is posed/animated without too much time spent tweaking controllers and avoiding distortion/clipping? Ideas about controllers/constraints/and other suggestions would be appreciated.

[image: Vyse's Belt]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe simply put a series of bones (like for example 6 bones) all around your belt, and parent them to the first spine bone?

[image]

Comment: Would pointing them up, down, sideways matter at all? Also, I figured similarly that I'd have the bones just be disconnected and parented to the spine, which I guess is what you're implying, but is there a way to keep them relatively connected, like some kind of bendy bone IK thing?

Comment: Edit: Nevermind, I'm an idiot. So orientating the bones that way would allow me to replace them with controller objects right on top of them. It's just that, I'd like to have some kind of smooth falloff when I move one bone, and it moves other ones a bit. I suppose location constraints would work here.

Comment: Bones pointing downards is probably the best solution. Sure you can parent a kind of belt root bone, the 6 bones will be parented to it and it will be parented to the bottom spine.

Comment: Okay. I'm going to test your series of bones with location constraints with an influence falloff and see how it goes. Thanks. You pointed me in the right direction. (I don't know why I didn't think about orientating the bones vertically...duh).